# Get clicked item of array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I've created a grid of objects called Cell. Each cell has following properties:

```
x coordinate
y coordinate
width
height
```

The width of a cell is equal to it's height. Every cell has got the same width/height.
There are 9*9 cells, one beside another, created by this algorithm:

```
cells = new Cell[9][0];

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    cells[i][j] = new Cell(i*cellWidth, j*cellHeight);
  }
}
```

The cell's constructor asks for the x and y coordinates. Now we got a grid of Cells.
When I touch the screen, I know the x and y coordinates where I touched the screen. This cell I touched should run a method called isTouched.

How can I find out which cell I've touched?

I've tried this algorithm:

```
public boolean isTouched(int zx, int zy) {
    if((zx >= x && zx <= x+cellSize) && (zy >= y && zy <= y+cellSize)) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

zx and zy are the touched coordinates. It checks whether the touched x axis is bigger or equal the cell's own x coordinate and if it's smaller than the cell's x coordinate + the cell's width. Same thing with the y coordinate.

It won't work as when I tap on a cell of the first row, the first element in the first row gets selected. When tapping on an element in the fifth row, the fifth element in the fifth row gets selected although I've pressed on another cell.

Here's a screenshot[image]

I can't find my mistake, any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: How is `isTouched()` getting called?

Comment: By again two forloops, calling isTouched in every cell

Answer (score 3):

It would be more efficient and easier to compute the cell which contains the touch point.

```
Cell touchedCell(int x, int y) {
    i = x / cellWidth;
    j = y / cellHeight;
    if (i >= 9 || j >= 9 || i < 0 || j < 0)
      return null;
    else
      return cell[i][j];
}
```

The array size is also off:

```
cells = new Cell[9][0];
```

This is whats causing the strange effect as there are only 9 cells in the array, since j will be multiplied by 0 when indexing `cell[i][j] == cell[i][0]` no matter what j.

should be

```
cells = new Cell[9][9];
```